# Java ParseInt Sanity Check

Tags: java, integer, parseint

I'm trying to parse a `int` from a `String` array element. Here is my code:

```
String length = messageContents[k].replace("Content-Length:", "").replace(" ", "");
System.out.println("Length is: " + length);
int test= Integer.parseInt(length);
```

The `System.out.println` returns the following: **Length is: 23**

However, when I try to parse the `String` into an `int`, a `java.lang.NumberFormatException` gets thrown;

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "23"
```

I'm a bit confused how 23 wont get parsed into an `int`.  I can  only assume that there is some other character in there that is preventing it, but I can't see it for the life of me.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

**Update**

```
Despite the String length having only two characters, Java reports its length as three:
Length is: '23'
Length of length variable is: 3
length.getBytes = [B@126804e
```

Comment: I notice that you have a trailing "." on the first line. Perhaps a copy-past error?

Comment: Ahh yes, ignore that.  Copy and paste error indeed.  Thanks :)

Comment: *"I can only assume that there is some other character in there that is preventing it, but I can't see it for the life of me."*  1) Enclose single quotes around the value in the `println` statement. 2) `System.out.println("How long is this piece of String? " + length.length());`

Comment: Thanks for that Andrew.
Length is: 23
Length of length is: 3

So where the heck is the extra character...Its not appearing in the output?

Comment: What do you get for length.getBytes()? I expect (byte[]) [50, 51]

Comment: System.out.println(length.getBytes());
[B@a6aeed

Comment: `System.out.println(Arrays.asList(length.getBytes()));` of course

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this variant:

```
int test= Integer.parseInt(length.trim());
```

Comment: That sorted it, thanks very much!
I'm assuming the byte 13 was counted as whitespace by the trim?

Comment: Not sure.  But `trim()` will get rid of most things in a `String` that are not visible.

Answer (score 3):

There might be unseen characters in this string.

My idea: use a regex with a Pattern/Matcher to remove all the non-numerals in your string, then parse it.

Comment: Normally I would.  But this problem has got me very interested in finding out why the extra character, whatever it may be, isn't appearing within the System.Out.

Comment: It could be one of those non-printable control characters that you can only find by issuing `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(length.getBytes()));`

Comment: [50, 51, 13] - I think 13 is a carriage return?

Comment: 13 is indeed the carriage return / line feed or `\n` character.